How to CopyResource with incompatible formats (DXGI_FORMAT_R10G10B10A2_UNORM to DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM )
I want to copy a ID3D11Texture2D from device to device (no CPU copying) and change the format from DXGI_FORMAT_R10G10B10A2_UNORM to DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM or an alternative CUDA-compatible format. For context, I am reading the back buffer in the Direct X video backend for Dolphin Emulator, and I am trying to feed it into a CNN.
Altering the format directly by changing D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC::Format to DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM causes CopyResource to fail silently:
  HRESULT hr = m_swap_chain->GetDXGISwapChain()->GetBuffer(
      0, __uuidof(ID3D11Texture2D), reinterpret_cast<void**>(backBuffer.GetAddressOf()));
  D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC desc;
  ComPtr<ID3D11Texture2D> shared_texture;

  backBuffer->GetDesc(&desc);

  desc.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_SHADER_RESOURCE;
  desc.MiscFlags = D3D11_RESOURCE_MISC_SHARED;
  desc.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;
  desc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM; // changed from DXGI_FORMAT_R10G10B10A2_UNORM
  hr = D3D::device->CreateTexture2D(&desc, nullptr, shared_texture.GetAddressOf()); 

  D3D::context->CopyResource(shared_texture.Get(), backBuffer.Get());// texture data is not  copied

I know this because I used the Graphics Diagnostics tool in VS and it showed the original back buffer properly, while the copied shared_texture displayed all zeros in the memory view. 
When I don't alter the format, and it remains as DXGI_FORMAT_R10G10B10A2_UNORM, CopyResource succeeds but registering the shared texture with CUDA via cudaGraphicsD3D11RegisterResource() fails.

DirectX has nothing builtin for this. On the CPU you could use DirectX https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTex, on the GPU you can try Media Foundation's Video Processor MFT https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/medfound/video-processor-mft which can convert MFVideoFormat_v410 to MFVideoFormat_ARGB32 for example. Depending on context, you might also want to to check if the emulator has an option to choose a different swapchain format, It may not be hardcoded for DXGI_FORMAT_R10G10B10A2_UNORM
